# Why R CMD Check failed with weird error in winbuilder ? "type must be LANGSXP at this point"

Tags: r, travis-ci, cran, appveyor, testthat

I am trying to propose an update of my package 'antaresRead' on CRAN.

When I use the service "https://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx" for R-devel to test my package, I have this error :

`test_check("antaresRead")
  Error in length(ans$indices) : type must be LANGSXP at this point
  Calls: test_check ... eval -> eval -> suppressMessages -> withCallingHandlers`

Logs are [here](https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/180115_152932_antaresRead_203/00check.log)

Why I have this error for this platform and with R-devel ? Can I correct It ?

When I use the same service with R-release and R-oldRelease, checks are OK :

- [Rrelease](https://win-builder.r-project.org/BSf358Iosg0m/00check.log)
- [RoldRelease](https://win-builder.r-project.org/J3qU2XQrAOeW/00check.log)

With the same code :

- Travis Is
  [OK](https://travis-ci.org/rte-antares-rpackage/antaresRead/jobs/328996034)
- appVeyor is [OK for 8 combinations](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/rte-antares-rpackage/antaresread)
- rhub is also OK for 8 platforms
- rhub::check(platform = 'debian-gcc-release')
- rhub::check(platform = 'macos-elcapitan-release')
- check_for_cran(platforms = "windows-x86_64-oldrel")
- check_for_cran(platforms = "windows-x86_64-patched")
- rhub::check(platform = 'fedora-clang-devel')
- rhub::check(platform        = 'fedora-gcc-devel')
- rhub::check(platform = 'debian-gcc-patched')
- rhub::check(platform =      'debian-gcc-devel')

Has anyone ever encountered this error? how to solve it?

What I did :

- Download the R-devel version for Windows found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rdevel.html) --> R 3.5.0
- Build and check my pacakge `antaresRead` for x64 --> build and check are OK
- Build and check my package for i386 --> build OK but faild in Check with the same error 
  `Error in length(ans$indices) : type must be LANGSXP at this point
  Calls: test_check ... eval -> eval -> suppressMessages -> withCallingHandlers`

Solution : 
- My bad, it's my code, it's my fault.
   The error come from this code

```
        districtLinks <- merge(districtLinks, districts[, .(district, x, y)], 
                           by.x = "toDistrict", by.y = "district")
```

districtLinks is empty sometimes and with the new version of R and data.table this provokes an error only in Windows 32bits. I added a check before.

Comment: Ugh, that's not a very useful error. It's not the same one as [this one from CRAN the checks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_antaresRead.html), is it?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Yes I also think it's not a very useful error...  CRAN [Error and Warnings Checks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_antaresRead.html) are for the actual release of my package antaresRead 2.0.2. My actual dev-version 2.0.3 correct these errors but I cannot purpose it in CRAN.  I am stuck because of the previous error.

Answer (score 1):

This error come because I wanted to merge an empty data.table with another data.table.

```
districtLinks <- merge(districtLinks, districts[, .(district, x, y)], 
                       by.x = "toDistrict", by.y = "district")
```

What I did is to add a check before the merge

```
if(!dim(districtLinks)[1]==0){
    districtLinks <- merge(districtLinks, districts[, .(district, x, y)], 
                           by.x = "toDistrict", by.y = "district")
}
```